# Simple xml returns null value for attribute field

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I want to use Simple XML to deserialize the following XML into a POJO:

```
<shippingInfo>
   <shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">9.8</shippingServiceCost>
   <shippingType>Flat</shippingType>
   <shipToLocations>Worldwide</shipToLocations>
   <expeditedShipping>true</expeditedShipping>
   <oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>
   <handlingTime>3</handlingTime>
</shippingInfo>
```

I have created the following class to do so. However, I'm having trouble in that the currencyId attribute isn't being properly deserialized.

```
@Root(name = "shippingInfo")
public class ShippingInfo {

    @Element(name = "shippingServiceCost", required = false)
    private BigDecimal shippingServiceCost;

    @Attribute(name = "currencyId", required = false)
    private String currencyId;

    @Element(name = "shippingType", required = false)
    private String shippingType;

    @Element(name = "shipToLocations" ,required = false)
    private String shipToLocations;

    @Element(name = "expeditedShipping", required = false)
    private Boolean expeditedShipping;

    @Element(name = "oneDayShippingAvailable", required = false)
    private Boolean oneDayShippingAvailable;

    @Element(name = "handlingTime", required = false)
    private Integer handlingTime;

    // Getters & Setters

    public BigDecimal getShippingServiceCost() {
        return shippingServiceCost;
    }

    public void setShippingServiceCost(BigDecimal shippingServiceCost) {
        this.shippingServiceCost = shippingServiceCost;
    }

    public String getCurrencyId() {
        return currencyId;
    }

    public void setCurrencyId(String currencyId) {
        this.currencyId = currencyId;
    }

    public String getShippingType() {
        return shippingType;
    }

    public void setShippingType(String shippingType) {
        this.shippingType = shippingType;
    }

    public String getShipToLocations() {
        return shipToLocations;
    }

    public void setShipToLocations(String shipToLocations) {
        this.shipToLocations = shipToLocations;
    }

    public Boolean isExpeditedShipping() {
        return expeditedShipping;
    }

    public void setExpeditedShipping(Boolean bool) {
        this.expeditedShipping = bool;
    }

    public Boolean isOneDayShippingAvailable() {
        return oneDayShippingAvailable;
    }

    public void setOneDayShippingAvailable(Boolean bool) {
        this.oneDayShippingAvailable = bool;
    }

    public Integer getHandlingTime() {
        return handlingTime;
    }

    public void setHandlingTime(Integer days) {
        this.handlingTime = days;
    }
}
```

I would expect the value of currencyId to be "USD" after deserializing, but I'm getting null. All the element values appear to deserialize properly. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Moreover, in a case such as the following instance:

```
<sellingStatus>
    <currentPrice currencyId="USD">125.0</currentPrice>
    <convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">125.0</convertedCurrentPrice>
    <bidCount>2</bidCount>
    <sellingState>EndedWithSales</sellingState>
</sellingStatus>
```

Where there are two attributes named currencyId on two distinct elements, how can I go about deserializing these into separate fields? I have created a similar SellingStatus class but am unsure how to distinguish between the currencyId attributes.

Thank you!

Edit: Per suggestions I tried adding a custom ShippingServiceCost class to ShippingInfo as follows:

```
@Element(name = "shippingServiceCost", required = false)
    private ShippingServiceCost shippingServiceCost;
```

Which in turn looks like this:

```
public class ShippingServiceCost {

    @Element(name = "shippingServiceCost", required = false)
    private BigDecimal shippingServiceCost;

    @Attribute(name = "currencyId", required = false)
    private String currencyId;

    // getters and setters
}
```

But when I try to access both the shippingServiceCost field and the currencyId field, I get null in every instance (even though I know there is data). Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the currencyID attribute from the shipping info class. Create a separate class for shipping service cost and add the currencyID attribute there. Then link the shipping service cost class in the shipping info class.

Comment: See my edit above, I tried this but I am still getting null for both shippingServiceCost and currencyId.

Comment: Can you annotate your shippingServiceCost class with the following "@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)"

Comment: I tried this, but still getting null values.

Answer (score 0):

For the above code, SimpleXML expects the currencyId to be present as `<shippingInfo currencyId="USD">`.

So to solve it, you need to create another class called ShippingServiceCost which will contain the currencyId attribute and the BigDecimal
This will also solve your second query. You can do it by creating two classes `CurrentPrice` and `ConvertedCurrentPrice` which will contain the currencyId attribute.

Comment: This is actually what I tried in the first place. However when I did this, I was getting null values for both the shipping service cost and the currency id. Placing the shipping service cost in the Shipping Info class solved that problem and I'm able to access it now, but I can't get at the currency id.

Comment: Update: I tried this (see edit to original post), but I'm still getting null values.

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution is creating a Converter class, see code below:

```
public class ShippingInfoConverter implements Converter<ShippingInfo> {

@Override
public ShippingInfo read(InputNode inputNode) throws Exception {
    ShippingInfo shippingInfo = new ShippingInfo();
    InputNode shippingServiceCostNode = inputNode.getNext("shippingServiceCost");
    shippingInfo.setShippingServiceCost(new BigDecimal(shippingServiceCostNode.getValue()));
    shippingInfo.setCurrencyId(shippingServiceCostNode.getAttribute("currencyId").getValue());
    shippingInfo.setShippingType(inputNode.getNext("shippingType").getValue());
    shippingInfo.setShipToLocations(inputNode.getNext("shipToLocations").getValue());
    shippingInfo.setExpeditedShipping(Boolean.parseBoolean(inputNode.getNext("expeditedShipping").getValue()));
    shippingInfo.setOneDayShippingAvailable(Boolean.parseBoolean(inputNode.getNext("oneDayShippingAvailable").getValue()));
    shippingInfo.setHandlingTime(Integer.valueOf(inputNode.getNext("handlingTime").getValue()));
    return shippingInfo;
}

@Override
public void write(OutputNode outputNode, ShippingInfo shippingInfo) throws Exception {
    OutputNode shippingServiceCostNode = outputNode.getChild("shippingServiceCost");
    shippingServiceCostNode.setValue(shippingInfo.getShippingServiceCost().toString());
    shippingServiceCostNode.setAttribute("currencyId", shippingInfo.getCurrencyId());
    outputNode.getChild("shippingType").setValue(shippingInfo.getShippingType());
    outputNode.getChild("shipToLocations").setValue(shippingInfo.getShipToLocations());
    outputNode.getChild("expeditedShipping").setValue(Boolean.toString(shippingInfo.isExpeditedShipping()));
    outputNode.getChild("oneDayShippingAvailable").setValue(Boolean.toString(shippingInfo.isOneDayShippingAvailable()));
    outputNode.getChild("handlingTime").setValue(Integer.toString(shippingInfo.getHandlingTime()));
}
```

}

Note how 'currencyId' is set, using the node's getAttribute method.

```
shippingInfo.setCurrencyId(shippingServiceCostNode.getAttribute("currencyId").getValue());
```

Also note how the element 'shippingServiceCost' gets the attribute

```
shippingServiceCostNode.setAttribute("currencyId", shippingInfo.getCurrencyId());
```

A few other things are need to get this working, starting with your POJO

```
@Root(name = "shippingInfo")
@Convert(ShippingInfoConverter.class)
public class ShippingInfo {

    @Element(name = "shippingServiceCost", required = false)
    private BigDecimal shippingServiceCost;

    private String currencyId;

    @Element(name = "shippingType", required = false)
    private String shippingType;

    @Element(name = "shipToLocations" ,required = false)
    private String shipToLocations;

    @Element(name = "expeditedShipping", required = false)
    private Boolean expeditedShipping;

    @Element(name = "oneDayShippingAvailable", required = false)
    private Boolean oneDayShippingAvailable;

    @Element(name = "handlingTime", required = false)
    private Integer handlingTime;

    // Getters & Setters

    public BigDecimal getShippingServiceCost() {
        return shippingServiceCost;
    }

    public void setShippingServiceCost(BigDecimal shippingServiceCost) {
        this.shippingServiceCost = shippingServiceCost;
    }

    public String getCurrencyId() {
        return currencyId;
    }

    public void setCurrencyId(String currencyId) {
        this.currencyId = currencyId;
    }

    public String getShippingType() {
        return shippingType;
    }

    public void setShippingType(String shippingType) {
        this.shippingType = shippingType;
    }

    public String getShipToLocations() {
        return shipToLocations;
    }

    public void setShipToLocations(String shipToLocations) {
        this.shipToLocations = shipToLocations;
    }

    public Boolean isExpeditedShipping() {
        return expeditedShipping;
    }

    public void setExpeditedShipping(Boolean bool) {
        this.expeditedShipping = bool;
    }

    public Boolean isOneDayShippingAvailable() {
        return oneDayShippingAvailable;
    }

    public void setOneDayShippingAvailable(Boolean bool) {
        this.oneDayShippingAvailable = bool;
    }

    public Integer getHandlingTime() {
        return handlingTime;
    }

    public void setHandlingTime(Integer days) {
        this.handlingTime = days;
    }

}
```

Adding the line below points SimpleXML to the converter class

```
@Convert(ShippingInfoConverter.class)
```

The other change is removing the @Attribute annotation.
One last thing required is that your driver class needs to have AnnotationStrategy enabled
when serialising and deserialing your objects.

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy());
```